# PostgreSQL query to select records which a specific value doesn't include in text array

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table like this

```
| id            | data                |
|---------------|---------------------|
| org:abc:basic | {org,org:abc:basic} |
| org:xyz:basic | {org,basic}         |
| org:efg:basic | {org}               |
```

I need to write a query to select all the rows which doesn't have the id inside the data column.

Or at least I need to query all the records which doesn't have a text starting from **org:** and ending with **:basic** within data.
Currently for this I try to run

```
SELECT * FROM t_permission WHERE 'org:%:basic' NOT LIKE ANY (data)
```

query which returns everything even the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `<>` operator with `ALL` against the array:

```
select *
from the_table
where id <> all(data);
```

Comment: This works. This and this `select *
from the_table
where not id = any(data);` and  `select *
from the_table
where id != all(data);`  are the same ? Because this also returns the same.

Comment: `<>` is the "not equals" operator in standard SQL. Postgres also accepts the non-standard `!=` operator which does exactly the same.